# Showing only maximum value for each point feature

Tags: qgis, field-calculator, error, function, maximum

I have a dataset with concentrations of copper from different stations taken over several years. I would like to show only the highest concentration `"mikromolar"` for each station `"STATN"`, and I tried using the

```
maximum("mikromolar", group_by:="STATN")
```

in the query builder, but all I get is error message when executing the query:

> OGR[3] error 1: SQL Expression Parsing Error: syntax error, unexpected
> $undefined, expecting ')'. Occurred around : maximum("mikromolar",
> group_by:="STATN")

How do I do this?

Comment: An error occurred when executing the query.
The data provider said:
OGR[3] error 1: SQL Expression Parsing Error: syntax error, unexpected $undefined, expecting ')'. Occurred around :
maximum("mikromolar", group_by:="STATN")

Answer (score 2):

If you use your expression in the select by expression, QGIS will examine the result as a logical value( 0 - False, non-zero - True).

I can give you two receipts to select max concentration at each station.

1. Add a virtual column to your table with the maximum value grouped by the station name. From the attribute table select **Open field calculator** and enter the followings:

[image]

Now you have max_cop column filled with the maximum of the station. In the a next step you can select those rows where the "micromolar" column is equal to the "max_cop" column.
If you change the values of "mikromolar" the virtual column will be updated if you close and open the attribute table.

2. Using the **DB Manager** module, you can use SQL to select even from shape files. Your SQL statement should be

   SELECT STATN, max(mikrobar) FROM your_table GROUP BY STATN;

This way you get a new attribute table only layer in your project if you select *Load as new layer* checkbox.

Comment: I think your SQL query lacks of `DISTINCT`

Comment: @Taras, no group by will do it.